# Is it possible to use the 'where' statement in elasticnet (SAS)?

Tags: sas

Here is the code I am using for variables selection:

```
proc glmselect data=abct; 
  where incex1=1;  
  title 'GLMSELECT with Elastic Net';
  model devmood_c = asetot age yrseduc sex employyn cohabyn caucyn asitot penntot 
                    anxdis ahealthuse ahospit ventxpwk acmn nhospit bmi comorb 
                    aqllimmn aqlsubmn aqlsympmn aqlemotmn aqlenvirmn aqltotmn 
                    smoke3gp nalcwkcurr
                    /selection=elasticnet(steps=120 L2=0.001 choose=validate); 
run;
```

The problem is that, when I run it, it tells me:

> ERROR: Variable incex1 is not on file WORK.ABCT.

This `incex1` variable is used to exclude people in our database that have score too high on a particular question. It works with LASSO, but even though the code is similar, doesn't seem to work with elasticnet.

Does anyone know how I could use it or if there is another way to exclude the patients who scored under a certain threshold on a questionnaire?

This is how `incex1` has been coded:

```
if devmood_c = 0 then incex1=1;
if devmood_c = 1 then incex1=1;
if devmood_c = . then incex1=0;
if bdisev > 2 then incex1=0;
label incex1 = "1=no mood at baseline or BDI > 20, 0=excluded";
```

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work with `proc glmselect`.  Are you absolutely sure it exists as named on `work.abct`?  That error suggests it does not.  If `where` was illegal (unlikely) it ought to give another error, unless there is something special about the modeling in `proc glmselect`.  You might try adding it as a data set criteria: `data=abct(where=(incex1=1))` instead of below to test that.

Comment: ^What Joe said.  Sometimes it might appear as though the column is named `incex1` but what you are actually looking at is the column label not the column name.  To double check this, in Base SAS open the table then go to View->Column Names.  I'm not sure where this is in EG. Perhaps someone else can verify.

Comment: In EG it is usually the default to show column names, but this varies by location; you can check in options -> Data -> Data General, uncheck "Use labels for column names", or hover over the label/name and it should show the other one.

Comment: If `incex` doesn't exist, could you use `where devmood_c in (0,1)` as per your derivation of `incex`? I haven't used `GLMSELECT` before so I may be wrong!

Answer (score 1):

This works in test data, so it is likely an issue with your source data not having the characteristics you expect.  For example,

```
ods graphics on;
proc glmselect data=sashelp.Leutrain valdata=sashelp.Leutest
               plots=coefficients;
where x1>0;
  model y = x2-x7129/
        selection=elasticnet(steps=120  l2=0.001 choose=validate);
run;
```

That works as expected.

Comment: I concur.  I cannot replicate this either.